# Icinga configuring error

Tags: monitoring, performance-monitoring

After configuring Icinga host list in host conf i got error like

```
root@server scripts]# icinga2 feature list
Disabled features: api gelf influxdb opentsdb
Enabled features: checker command compatlog debuglog graphite ido-pgsql livestatus mainlog notification perfdata statusdata syslog
[root@server scripts]# service icinga2 checkconfig
Checking configuration: Done
[root@server scripts]# /etc/init.d/icinga2 start
Checking configuration: Done
Starting Icinga 2: Error starting Icinga. Check '/var/log/icinga2/startup.log' for details.
```

Comment: what does `/var/log/icinga2/startup.log` say?

Comment: nothing in there

Comment: [root@server scripts]# cat /var/log/icinga2/startup.log
[root@server scripts]#

Comment: is it still running? you might need to restart icinga2 instead of just starting.
if the process is still running you might not be able to start it again unless it is properly stopped.

Additionally pid files leftovers or similiar might be a reason.

Comment: Can you explain it clearly **Additionally pid files leftovers or similiar might be a reason**